# Menu link security trimming

Tags: asp.net, menu, sitemap, security-trimming

I am having a problem with security trimming of menu links provided by the sitemap. If I set `securityTrimmingEnabled="false"`, my menu works but there's no security trimming. If I set `securityTrimmingEnabled="true"`, my menu just disappears. How can I fix this?

In `web.config`, I have:

```
<siteMap defaultProvider="XmlSiteMapProvider" enabled="true" >
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="XmlSiteMapProvider"
             description="Default SiteMap provider."
             type="System.Web.XmlSiteMapProvider"
             siteMapFile="Web.sitemap"
             securityTrimmingEnabled="true" />
  </providers>
</siteMap>
```

In `Site.master`, I have:

```
<div class="clear hideSkiplink">
    <asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" CssClass="menu" DataSourceID="SiteMapDataSource1">
    </asp:Menu>
    <asp:SiteMapDataSource ID="SiteMapDataSource1" runat="server" />
</div>
```

In `Web.sitemap`, I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<siteMap xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/AspNet/SiteMap-File-1.0" >
  <siteMapNode url="" title="***">
    <siteMapNode url="" title="***">
      <siteMapNode url="~/***.aspx" title="***" />
      <siteMapNode url="~/***.aspx" title="***" />
      <siteMapNode url="~/***.aspx" title="***" />
      <siteMapNode url="~/***.aspx" title="***" />
    </siteMapNode>
    <siteMapNode url="" title="***">
      <siteMapNode url="~/Account/***.aspx" title="***" />
      <siteMapNode url="~/Account/***.aspx" title="***" />
      <siteMapNode url="~/Account/***.aspx" title="***" />
      <siteMapNode url="~/Account/***.aspx" title="***" />
    </siteMapNode>
  </siteMapNode>
</siteMap>
```

Comment: You have not specified the allowed roles on your nodes - so when securityTrimmingEnabled is enabled you are not in an allowed role (as it has none) so no items display (see the docs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178428.aspx)

Comment: thanks kevin. ive done what u said. now some of the nodes look like this: <siteMapNode url="~/Account/***.aspx" title="***" roles="***" /> but it still doesnt work. plus, some of the nodes doesnt need any authentication. why does my whole menu goes completely blank :(

Comment: With securityTrimmingEnabled off - all items are displayed by default. With it on all items are *not* displayed by default - they only display if the user is in one of the allowed roles - you can't mix the two, so if you leave the roles atttibute blank for a node it will never display

Comment: isnt there a way to allow some nodes for everyone to access?

Comment: I think you can do roles="*" (as per this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dannychen/archive/2006/03/16/553005.aspx)

Comment: thanks kevin. roles="*" does work. you have been really helpful.

Comment: No worries - will add all this as an answer so you can mark it in case any one else is having the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify roles on your nodes like this (as per this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178428.aspx)

```
 <siteMapNode title="Support" description="Support" url="~/Customers/Support.aspx" roles="Customers" />
```

All nodes are by default not displayed when securityTrimmingEnabled is enabled unless you are in one of the allowed roles. To allow all roles you can do this roles="*" (as described here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dannychen/archive/2006/03/16/553005.aspx)